# Deleting a Firestore collection with async/await in Python

Tags: python, firebase, asynchronous, async-await, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Admin SDK with python and would like to delete a Firestore collection with Async/Await clause.

The [official document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-delete-collection) says that (non-Async/Await) deleting should be done like this:

```py
def delete_collection(col_ref, batch_size):
    docs = col_ref.limit(batch_size).stream()
    deleted = 0

    for doc in docs:
        print(f'Deleting doc {doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
        doc.reference.delete()
        deleted = deleted + 1


    if deleted >= batch_size:
        return delete_collection(col_ref, batch_size)
```

But, this does not work well in Async/Await version. If I put `AsyncCollectionReference` in the `col_ref`, it will cause this error:

```
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
```

Is it possible to fix this probem? Or, is it an totally wrong idea to do Async/Await batch delete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding async/await statements to your code:

```
async def delete_collection(coll_ref, batch_size):
    docs = coll_ref.limit(batch_size).stream()
    deleted = 0

    async for doc in docs:
        print(f"Deleting doc {doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}")
        await doc.reference.delete()
        deleted = deleted + 1

    if deleted >= batch_size:
        return delete_collection(coll_ref, batch_size)
```